# How to send field value in custom directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two field first and second.I added a custom directive in first field .But I able to get first field value in directive .I want “last” field value in same directive. I used attributes but it will not work here is my code

I added custom directive in "First field"

```
.directive("testfirst", function() {
        return {
            restrict: "A",
            require: 'ngModel',

            link: function(scope, element, attributes, modelVal) {

                modelVal.$validators.testfirst= function(val) {
                  if(val.length > 0 && !(attributes.last && attributes.last.length < 4)){

                    return false
                  }
                   return true
                };
                scope.$watch("val", function() {
                    modelVal.$validate();
                });

            }

        };
    })
```

I want "last field value" here is custom directive .I used attribute but it not work

here is my code
http://plnkr.co/edit/EYsUDkG3Kne1mEfEI8GT?p=preview

Comment: is there a good reason to use `ng-repeat`? It seems like it's making a mess in your case. I think you want to pass the **model** of the _last_ input field into the _first_ with an attribute, but they share the same model name (due to `ng-repeat`)

Comment: what is better solutiom

Comment: there is just a lot of dependancies and specific rules that makes it very difficult to work with using `ng-repeat`. But it's up to you to design it

Comment: can you share you plunker with better solution

Comment: please share an example